How to remove a screen from tab bar in React Native
So, I deleted the code that shows the topic screen in the tabs bar. The problem is, when I run the app it's still there. I tried clearing the cache, deleting the .expo folder, and re-running the app. Nothing works. And I need to figure this out soon.


import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';
import TopicScreen from './topics'; 
import DashboardScreen from './dashboard';

export default function stackLayout() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName="topics" >
      <Stack.Screen name="topics" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={TopicScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="tabs" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={TabLayout}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  return (
    <Tabs 
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
      }}>

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="dashboard"
        options={{
          title: 'Dashboard',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="explore"
        options={{
          title: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'search-circle-sharp' : 'search-circle-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs> 
  );
}



Here's an image...


Uninstall the application completely, then test the following method: Product -> Clean Build Folder. After performing the 'npx react-native start --reset-cache' command, run the metro again. To run on the iOS side, you can run npx react-native run-ios or manually from Xcode.

I have a problem same to you. I try stop the server and run it back with '-c' in it
npx expo start -c

It will clear the cache and rebuild it back and the tabs is gone now. It works for me though. Correct me if I'm wrong.
